# See bindings before debugging

Tags: wpf, debugging, binding, static

Is it possible to see static binding before debugging?

I tried already with that:

```
Background="{Binding Source={x:Static local:DataBase.TestFarbe}}"
```

and with that:

```
Background="{Binding Source={x:Static local:DataBase.TestFarbe}}"
```

What I know is that

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UC_InfoHead}}, Path=TypeText}"
```

for Binding between Xaml and his class already works

EDIT:
as Example

I created a UserControl with bindings:

[image]

Then when I add my UserControl to my Window
[image]

I am able to see my Text although it is a binding

Comment: What does "before debugging" mean? And what's the difference between your first two snippets? What are you trying to bind to? Maybe you just want to set the property to static value?: `Background="{x:Static local:DataBase.TestFarbe}"`?

Comment: I have not explained it sufficiently:
Visual Studio can apparently make some bindings visible before debugging. For example, in my third code example, my Xaml editor shows me the text after "create new". In my first two examples, this is only visible after debugging in the program itself. 

Between my first both example there is no difference i think and yes i try to bind a static value

Comment: i mean "Build projekt"

Comment: Whether you see the value at *design* time depends on the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer isn't directly equivalent to running the application for efficiency reasons.

One of the things that it will not do is instantiate statics which you have bound. Which means just a binding to a static will not work in the designer.

You might think if it merges resource dictionaries using app.xaml then "just" instantiating a static class seems pretty simple. They need to draw the line somewhere though.

Hence, your third example works because the designer needs to turn xaml into UI and that binding is to a property of a piece of UI which is therefore instantiated.

Binding to a static isn't

Your alternatives include:

- Wrap your static property with a viewmodel property where that
  viewmodel is instantiated in xaml.
- Provide a design time datacontext which mocks data completely or
  somehow builds a fixed instance of your viewmodel.
- FallbackValue and TargetNullValue on your binding to give a "hard coded" default.
- Write a markup extension which will read the static.

The latter isn't quite as difficult as it seems if you just want read only data. MarkUpExtension has just one method - ProvideValue to override. You "just" need a class inherits from MarkUpExtension with that method:

```
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Return value from static class' property here.
    }
```

It seems what you want is a brush for the background, so this is presumably read only and a markup extension might be your best bet.